# Как правильнее реализовать получение значений из динамических полей ввода?

Tags: reactjs

Поля ввода генерируются динамически + возможность добавления новых полей ввода такого же типа. Я сохраняю значения в объекте: [название поля + index]: value. Все работает хорошо, но я не продумал отправку значений на сервер — я просто не знаю как вытащить значения по ключу, ведь они все уникальны.

```
  // содержит значения полей ввода
  const [fieldsValue, setFieldsValue] = useState<{[key: string]: string}>({});

  newFields.fields.map((field: string, index: number) =>
    <label key={ field + index }>
      { field }
      <input
      type="text"
      onChange={(evt: {[key: string]: any}) => setFieldsValue({ ...fieldsValue, [field + index]: evt.target.value })}
      value={fieldsValue[field + index] || ''}
      />
    </label>
  )
```

Мне нужно отправить значение какого-либо поля, но ключ этого поля, в принципе, уникальный.

Если есть идеи или замечания — буду рад обратной связи.

Comment: Не понятно, что именно не получается. Добавьте в вопрос код, как вы что сохраняете и что вы хотите сделать при отправке. По хорошему, достать из объекта значения по ключу не должно быть "сложным"

Comment: @SwaD Внес изменения.

Comment: Вообще `[field + index]` - очень плохая затея - если порядок значений в **newFields.fields** изменится, то у вас все сломается. По поводу отправки - вы же должны знать, что должны отправить. Это где то кнопка есть? Как предпологается отправка? И есть вы можете, переделайте `fields` из `string[]` в массив объектов вида `{ field: string, id: string | number}`. При сохранении используйте внутренний **id**, тогда будете гарантированно знать, какой элемент какой id имеет